# React Refs not working with a dynamically generated component in a higher-order component (HOC)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx, higher-order-components

I'm encountering an issue with React refs that's a bit perplexing. I have a higher-order component (HOC) that dynamically generates child components based on a prop, and I'm trying to use refs to access those child components. However, it seems like the refs aren't being properly set, and I can't figure out why.

Here's a simplified example of my code:

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

const DynamicComponent = ({ name }) => {
  // Some component logic here...
  return <div>{name}</div>;
};

const HOC = ({ dynamicComponentProps }) => {
  const dynamicRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(dynamicRef.current); // This logs 'null'
    // Some other logic with dynamicRef.current...
  }, [dynamicRef.current]);

  const renderDynamicComponent = () => {
    return dynamicComponentProps.map((props, index) => (
      <DynamicComponent ref={dynamicRef} key={index} {...props} />
    ));
  };

  return <div>{renderDynamicComponent()}</div>;
};

const App = () => {
  const dynamicComponentProps = [
    { name: 'Component A' },
    { name: 'Component B' },
    { name: 'Component C' },
  ];

  return <HOC dynamicComponentProps={dynamicComponentProps} />;
};
```

In the `useEffect` block inside the `HOC`, the `dynamicRef.current` is always `null`, even though the components are rendered. Am I missing something about refs in dynamically generated components, or is there a better approach to achieve what I'm trying to do?

**What I Tried:**

I attempted to use React refs in a higher-order component (HOC) that dynamically generates child components based on a prop. I created a ref (`dynamicRef`) within the HOC and assigned it to each dynamically generated child component.

**What I Expected:**

I expected that when I access `dynamicRef.current` in the `useEffect` block, it would point to the last dynamically generated child component, allowing me to perform actions or access properties of that component.

**What Actually Resulted:**

Surprisingly, when I logged `dynamicRef.current`, it always showed `null`, indicating that the refs weren't being properly set. Despite the components being rendered, the ref wasn't pointing to any of them.

Comment: You need to use `forwardRef`

Comment: Refs do not work with functional components, since they are not instantiated. Why would you need a ref to a component? Usual use case is to get a ref to DOM inside a child component right?

Comment: Also, there is this problem of you using a single ref for multiple components. Your data structures are not matching for the ref and the assignment of the ref. You will need to use an array. Can you explain your use case so I can write a more contextual useful answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to assign the same ref for all your components. a ref needs to be assined to a single instance of a component so we can modify your code to the following

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";

const DynamicComponent = React.forwardRef(({ name }, ref) => {
  // Some component logic here...
  return <div ref={ref}>{name}</div>;
});

const HOC = ({ dynamicComponentProps }) => {
  const dynamicRefs = dynamicComponentProps.map(() => useRef(null));

  useEffect(() => {
    dynamicRefs.forEach((ref) => {
      console.log(ref.current); // This should log the div element
      // Some other logic with ref.current...
    });
  }, [dynamicRefs]);

  const renderDynamicComponent = () => {
    return dynamicComponentProps.map((props, index) => (
      <DynamicComponent ref={dynamicRefs[index]} key={index} {...props} />
    ));
  };

  return <div>{renderDynamicComponent()}</div>;
};

const App = () => {
  const dynamicComponentProps = [
    { name: "Component A" },
    { name: "Component B" },
    { name: "Component C" },
  ];

  return <HOC dynamicComponentProps={dynamicComponentProps} />;
};

export default App;
```

in this updated version we have a seperate ref foreach component.
to make this work we add to modfiy a few other things as well

1. changed DynamicComponent to forwardRef so that we can pass a ref
2. in the useEffect we log the array of refs
3. in renderDynamiccomponent we assign a different ref to each component

**EDIT**

As pointed out in the comments the above code does break react rule of calling hook in side a loop so we can change the code a little instead of having an array of refs we now have a ref containings an array

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";

const DynamicComponent = React.forwardRef(({ name }, ref) => {
  // Some component logic here...
  return <div ref={ref}>{name}</div>;
});

const HOC = ({ dynamicComponentProps }) => {
  const dynamicRefs = useRef(
    dynamicComponentProps.map(() => ({ current: null }))
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    dynamicRefs.current.forEach((ref) => {
      console.log(ref.current); // This should log the div element
      // Some other logic with ref.current...
    });
  }, [dynamicRefs.current]);

  const renderDynamicComponent = () => {
    return dynamicComponentProps.map((props, index) => (
      <DynamicComponent
        ref={dynamicRefs.current[index]}
        key={index}
        {...props}
      />
    ));
  };

  return <div>{renderDynamicComponent()}</div>;
};

const App = () => {
  const dynamicComponentProps = [
    { name: "Component A" },
    { name: "Component B" },
    { name: "Component C" },
  ];

  return <HOC dynamicComponentProps={dynamicComponentProps} />;
};

export default App;
```

Comment: I think this breaks a rule of hooks `dynamicComponentProps.map(() => useRef(null));`. It will call `useRef` variable number or times

Comment: @Konrad you are right and i updated my answer accordingly

Comment: @user23327911 Also note that The usage of `index` as the key in `renderDynamicComponent` might lead to issues in certain scenarios. It's generally recommended to use a unique identifier from your data if possible.